# Transcription software playback issues

Tags: gstreamer, audacity, playback

I need to transcribe some audio recordings. Audacity replays the WAV files perfectly, yet when I try to use dedicated software (Parlatype or gTranscribe) the playback jumps and stutters in places.

How can I resolve this issue? Could it be due to Parlatype's Gstreamer Dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Check quality of your audio file in a separate audio player such as Vlc whether it contains any segments that cannot be clearly played. Does the issue occur at the beginning of the recording that could suggest there are some issues with the file format, or at a later stage, which could suggest that there are some corrupted segments in the audio recording. You can also consider to try another dedicated software for audio transcription such as [Transcribear](https://transcribear.com) a free web based editor for manual audio transcription. It uses media player that is build in within user's web browser.